# How to play a video after the start of the app

Tags: android

How can I play a Video before the App starts?

I made an Animation which shows my Name and the Name of the App and I want to have this Video as an Intro.

Comment: It is best to ask 1 question per post, so please edit this post to 1 question and then add another question with the 2nd half

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some code, my friend.

Comment: @ViratSingh This is only an question how to do this.. I ask for code, the idea ..

Answer (score 0):

Try with `VideoView`.
Please check sample code

```
package com.dwivedi.splashscreenexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                try {
                        VideoView videoHolder = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
                        Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
                                        + "/" + R.raw.splash);
                        videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);

                        videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                        jump();
                                }

                        });
                        videoHolder.start();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                        jump();
                }
        }

        protected void jump() {

           Intent  intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```